# foreach statement in Body MailMessage C#

Tags: c#, mailmessage

How would I pass a List through an email body? This is what I have, that returns `vehicleNames` with a `Count`. I need to be able to cycle through the `Count` and get each `Name` from the list to append to the email body. I have tried adding a `foreach` to the email's `Body`, but I get an intellisense error each time, so if it is possible to do, I'm not doing it right. I appreciate the help.

```
 adminEmail.Body = "<div style='font-family: Arial, sans-serif default; font-size: 11pt;'><h2>Hello " + approverName + ",</h2>" +
                    "<p>A new key request has been received. Please log in to manage your request(s).</p></div>" +
                    "<div><hr align=\"left\" width=\"75%\"><br /><h3>Reservation Details</h3>" +
                    "<ul><li>Driver: " + employee.FirstName + " " + employee.LastName + "</li>" +
                    "<li>Driver Email: " + employee.HawkeyeEmail + "</li>" +
                    "<li>Destination: " + reservation.Destination + "</li>" +
                    "<li>Purpose of Trip: " + reservation.PurposeOfTrip + "</li>" +
                    "<li>Transporting Students: " + reservation.TransportStudentsFG.ToString() + "</li>" +
   help please! --> "<li>Vehicle(s): " + vehicleNames.ToString() + "</li></ul>" +  <-- help!
                    "<p><a href='" + reservationDetailsLink + "'>Click here to view and approve the request.</a></p><br /></div>";
```

Comment: string.Join(",", vehicleNames)

Comment: Perfect! @Marcel Can you add that as an answer? Get those extra reputation points ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String.Join(..,..) from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Join_System_String_System_String___

Like so:

string.Join(",", vehicleNames)